# Inheritance + Foreign Keys

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been absolutely racking my brain over this, and can't seem to work out how to get around the issue. Please note that I have cut alot of irrelevant fields out of my models

I am in the middle of coding up my SQL-Alchemy models, and have encountered the following issue:

Due to multiple billing systems, each with completely different attributes, and due to the different types of Subscription attributes (i.e. usernames, node locations, etc), I have had to go down the polymorphic inheritance road.

```
class Subscription(Base):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    secret = db.Column(postgresql.BYTEA)
    type = db.Column(SubscriptionType.db_type())
    status = db.Column(StatusType.db_type())
    subscription_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

    __tablename__ = 'subscription'
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'public'}

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on' : type}

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Subscription: %r>' % self.id

class Product1(Subscription):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity' : SubscriptionType.product1}    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('public.subscription.id'), 
        primary_key = True)
    billing_system = db.Column(
        db.Integer, 
        db.ForeignKey('public.billing_system.id')
    )

class BillingSystem(Base):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    type = db.Column(BillingSystemType.db_type())

    __tablename__ = 'billing_system'
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'public'}

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on' : type}

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Subscription: %r>' % self.id

class BillingSystem1(BillingSystem):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity' : BillingSystemType.billingsystem1}    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('public.billing_system.id'), 
        primary_key = True)
    billing_system = db.Column(
        db.Integer, 
        db.ForeignKey('public.billing_system.id')
    )
    foo = db.Column(db.Integer)
    bar = db.Column(db.Integer)

 class BillingSystem2(BillingSystem):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity' : BillingSystemType.billingsystem2}    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('public.billing_system.id'), 
        primary_key = True)
    billing_system = db.Column(
        db.Integer, 
        db.ForeignKey('public.billing_system.id')
    )
    bing = db.Column(db.Integer)
    boo = db.Column(db.Integer)


    __tablename__ = 'billing_system_product2'
    __table_args__ = {'schema':'public'}
```

It is all working fine, except for one thing.

Say that I run the following:

```
>>> a = Product1()
>>> b = BillingSystem.objects.get(1)
>>> a.billing_system = b
>>> session.add(a)
>>> session.commit()
```

I will receive the following error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'BillingSystem1' 'INSERT INTO
```

I understand what it is saying, and I have tried the following.

```
>>> a.billing_system = b.id
```

This only stores the ID, and when I try to retreive the associated object, I instead receive an integer. This involves me having to do an additional query. I would expect that this isn't the way to go.

I have also tried adding foreign keys for all of the billing system IDs to the Product1 Model

```
class BillingSystem1(BillingSystem):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity' : BillingSystemType.billingsystem1}    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('public.billing_system.id'), 
        primary_key = True)
    billing_system = db.Column(
        db.Integer, 
        db.ForeignKey('public.billing_system.id'),
        db.ForeignKey('public.billing_system1.id'),
        db.ForeignKey('public.billing_system2.id'),
    )
    foo = db.Column(db.Integer)
    bar = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

This also didn't work at all, and I received the same ProgrammingError exception stating that the type can't adapt.

I have trawled the manual, and can't find how to do it, but I need some form of magical option to allow this to happen:

```
>>> a = BillingSystem.query.get(1)
>>> type(a)
BillingSystem
```

Instead of:

```
>>> a = BillingSystem.query.get(1)
>>> type(a)
BillingSystem1
```

Is anyone able to shed any light on how I can query my set of Polymorphic models for an ID, and only obtain the class of the base model?

I feel that this will solve my problem, im just not sure of how to work it out.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, and I would really like to find out where I am going wrong (I have also been awake way too long, so that isn't helping).

Cheers,
Rhys

Comment: This probably isn't going to be a super-helpful answer for you, but it seems that in order to find out if I can help you, I will have to read a huge amount of your code and figure out little details. 

The best way to get an answer on this site is to pare the code down until it is incredibly simple but still gives the same error. Then you can ask a very specific question: "why does line 3 of these 4 lines of code throw an error?" As an added bonus you usually actually *solve the problem* when you go through this process. Good luck!

Comment: Some rest and your advice helped alot! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Subscription(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    secret = db.Column(postgresql.BYTEA)
    type = db.Column(SubscriptionType.db_type())
    status = db.Column(StatusType.db_type())
    subscription_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

    billing_system_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, 
        db.ForeignKey('public.billing_system.id')
    )
    billing_system = db.relationship('BillingSystem', backref='subscriptions')
```

So what I have done is:

1 ) Shifted the Subscription.billing_system_id Foreign Key up to the Base Subscription Model
2 ) Added in the Subscription.billing_system Relationship

So now I am doing this:

```
>>> o = BillingSystem.query.get(1)
>>> a = Product1()
>>> a.billing_system_id = o.id
```

Which results in:

```
>>> a.billing_system.subscriptions
[<cPanel Hosting Reseller: 2>]
>>> a.billing_system_id
2
```

So unless I am doing something wrong here, it seems to work. I just can't pass the actual BillingSystem object, I actually have to set the ID. It is still referencially enforced when the model is saved though, so I don't see too many issues with it.

Thanks for your help :)